# Create 2 separate instances of the same prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create 2 separate instances of the keypad prefab below.
The problem is that it doesn't matter on which one of them I tap, they both respond and show the same output.
My guess is that they both refer to the same script attached to the prefab and I don't know how to create 2 separate instances of the same script.

[image: Keypads Image]

Here the script attached to them:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LockSystemScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text ScreenText;

    private int _taps;
    private Color _startColor;
    private AudioSource _clickSound;
    private RequestsManager _requestsManager;
    private Vector3 _screenCenter;

    private void Start ()
    {
        _taps = 0;
        _startColor = ScreenText.color;
        _clickSound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        _requestsManager = RequestsManager.Instance;
        _screenCenter = GetScreenCenter();
    }

    private void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(_screenCenter);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100) && hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Button") && _taps <= 3)
            {
                ScreenText.text += hit.transform.name;
                _clickSound.Play();
                _taps++;
            }

            if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Submit"))
            {
                _clickSound.Play();
                StartCoroutine(_requestsManager.InputCode(ScreenText.text, ScreenText));
            }

            if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Reset"))
            {
                _taps = 0;
                ScreenText.color = _startColor;
                ScreenText.text = "";
                _clickSound.Play();
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetScreenCenter()
    {
        float screenX = Screen.width / 2;
        float screenY = Screen.height / 2;
        return new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the two prefabs share the same tag? Because the script is listening to hits on tags, not on individual game objects

Comment: YES! that was the problem! I didn't think of it, Thank you very much!

Comment: Afaik `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` is true global not just if the mouse is over the object. You should rather go for [`OnPointetEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerEnter.html), 
 [`OnPointerExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerExit.html) and [`OnPointerClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerClick.html) or directly use a `Button` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do actually have two separate instances of `LockSystem` and with each of them a separate instance of `LockSystemScript`. You made a mistake is in the following line though:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100) && hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Button") && _taps <= 3)
```

What you're doing here is you're checking if the `Raycast()` hits an object and if this object is a `Button`. The problem is that `Update()` is being called on every `MonoBehaviour` in your scene, so it is called for both instances of `LockSystemScript` and no matter what `LockSystem` you are looking at, you are looking at a `Button` and the above statement is `true`.

What you should be doing is the following:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100) && hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Button") && _taps <= 3 && hit.transform.isChildOf(this.transform))
```

This way you're checking if the `Button` you are looking at actually belongs to the script in which `Update()` is run right now.

Comment: I just read the new comments below your question. Yes, changing the tag for every instance is a possibility but it is not a very scalable one. I would leave the tag the same for every instance and try my approach.